# Issue with Swift code to set default app handler for a given file type ("Foundation" not being imported?)

Tags: swift

Would like to use Swift to change the default application that handles a given filetype (eg, PDF) on MacOS.

Getting an error when running on macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) / Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175) — maybe "Foundation" is not being imported correctly? Searched a bunch on the web but couldn't find a solution for this...

```
import Foundation

LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType("com.adobe.pdf" as CFString, LSRolesMask.all, "com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro" as CFString)
```

Here's the error I'm getting, any ideas please? Thanks!

```
Playground execution failed: Test KM.playground:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType'
LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType("com.adobe.pdf" as CFString, LSRolesMask.all, "com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro" as CFString)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Test KM.playground:3:68: error: use of unresolved identifier 'LSRolesMask'
LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType("com.adobe.pdf" as CFString, LSRolesMask.all, "com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro" as CFString)
                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1444955-lssetdefaultrolehandlerforconten). You have to import the “CoreServices” framework.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For some reason on my version of Swift (or one if the modules?) I had to use LSRolesMask.All (vs LSRolesMask.all).